# cannot resolve getAssets() method

Tags: android, inputstream, assets

hi i have been having trouble with the getAsset() method. i trying to get a xml file from the assets folder with the getAsset() to be put into a inputStream.

CODE:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List people;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            InputStream is =  getAssets().open("people.xml");
            people = XMLParser.readPeople(is);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<people>
   <person>
       <name>joe</name>
       <dob>11/08/16</dob>
       <gender>male</gender>
   </person>
</people>
```

can anyone tell me what going on with the getAssets() method

Comment: what issue are you facing ? is it throwing exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
      try {
            InputStream is =  getAssets().open("people.xml");
            people = XMLParser.readPeople(is);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

use this

```
        try {
               AssetManager assetManager = getBaseContext().getAssets();
                InputStream is =  assetManager.open("people.xml");
                people = XMLParser.readPeople(is);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: it doing the same thing with getBaseContext()

Comment: @mohammadalam try to `clean` the project and `rebuild` it .

Comment: @mohammadalam glad to help you.