# Cannot resolve getBaseContext() method

Tags: java, android-studio, android-assets

I want to read from a JSON-file. I did what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761289/cannot-resolve-getassets-method), but it couldn't resolve the getBaseContext()-method. I read that I should use Context instead of this, but there remains an error saying "non static method getAssets() cannot be referenced from a static context". How can I resolve this? Code looks like this:

```
AssetManager assetManager = Context.getAssets();
InputStream is = assetManager.open("Test.json");
```

I assume Context refers to the Activity in which the instance is created and so does getBaseContext(). Am I wrong with that?

Comment: From which function and class are you trying to call getContext() ?

Comment: My own, I called it JSONTranslater. It has a method to parse the JSON-file which calls loadJSONfromAssets (where the code snippet comes from).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you need to use context to read from assets, for this you have to send a Context reference to your function:

```
public static String loadJSONfromAssets(Context context)
```

Depending on where you are calling the function, you can access the context by using `getContext()`, `getActivity()` (from Fragment) or directly `this` (from Activity).